# how to populate a drop down list in MVC with given values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a view model with a foreign key to another model, base on that, I want to create a dropDownList that will show me the selected value name and will give me all the other option so I can change it to what ever I want.
this is my create form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Failed creating the feed")
<fieldset>
    <legend>FeedViewModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FeedId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LinkUrl)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LinkUrl)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LinkUrl)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FolderId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

I want to create the dropDownList at the Last div, I already have the values form my model.
How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to do this in the above templating language? if so please provide more detail

Comment: I have already found the answer, but due to my reputation points I can't publish it yet
thanks for everyone

Comment: See my DDL tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should user Html.DropDownListFor extension method:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ImageId, new SelectListItem[] {
            new SelectListItem {
                Selected = true,
                Text = "Text 1",
                Value = "Fileld Value 1"
            },
            new SelectListItem {
                Selected = false,
                Text = "Text 2",
                Value = "Fileld Value 2"
            }
        });
```

Of course second parameter IEnumerable can be populated from database instead of hardcoding.

Comment: thanks 
in order to get it from the DB do I need to place another @model at the top of my view file? I tried to do that but it messed up my page.

Comment: You can only have one @model per view. You have to add a new property containing select list items to your existing model. Alternatively you can pass select list items to the view using ViewBag or ViewData.